# GMP integer size limit reached?

Tags: memory, gmp

I have written an implementation of Toom multiplication with GMP. I tested multiplication of 2 numbers of around 7000 digits (23,000 bits) and it worked perfectly. However when I tried it with 70000 digits (230,000 bits) the program started producing wrong answers.

I am using a 32 bit system. Could GMP run out of memory to use? I did not get any error so I think this is unlikely. If this is not the case I suspect some loss of precision somewhere.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. It reads like "my program produces wrong answers, could it be because GMP is running out of memory?" That seems like a totally random diagnosis that bears no resemblance whatsoever to your description of the problem. You should put much more effort into describing the problem and, if you want to propose a diagnosis, provide some evidence to back that diagnosis up. Otherwise, let other people diagnose the problem.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't understand how my question doesn't make sense. The program explicitly works for small values but not large; that's why I believe there is an issue of precision. That is my evidence, in addition to the fact that the entire program makes extensive usage of GMP features.

Comment: Isn't it far more likely that the bug is in your code than that's in a widely-used and extensively-reviewed library like GMP?

Comment: What is the size of limb i.e. `sizeof(mp_limb_t)` for your configuration (even if you have 32-bit OS, the limb might be defined as `unsigned long long` as your CPU might have 64-bit registers) ? Why you are implementing Toom multiplication if it's implemented by library itself (that is, `mpz_mul` "redirects" to proper algorithm based essentially on number of limbs of operands) ? The library has defined multiple thresholds for various mul implementations (defined in gmp-impl.h as number of limbs). For very large operands (thousends limbs) FFT multiplication might be preffered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general GMP allocates data on heap with "malloc and friends". If data cannot be allocated properly, then it invokes standard `abort()` function (so process should be simply aborted), see `memory.c`:

```
ret = malloc (size);
if (ret == 0)
  {
    fprintf (stderr, "GNU MP: Cannot allocate memory (size=%lu)\n", (long) size);
    abort ();
  }
```

It's rather impossible to tell what went wrong in your calculations, without taking much more details (see my comment).